# using one validation for two input codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I want to have one validation for two input
ex I have input agendaCode and agendaNumber
I want codeigniter check the concation value of both input at the same time so I will have code like

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('agendaCode/agendaNumber','my_callback_function);
```

but its return error

---

i know the answer by using

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('agendaCode','my_callback_function[agendaNumber]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass one field name to the set_rules() method when doing it that way:

- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-validation-rules

However, you can pass an array:

- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-rules-using-an-array

So:

```
$config = array(
    array(
         'field' => 'agendaCode',
         'label' => 'Agenda Code',
         'rules' => 'callback_my_function'
    ),
    array(
         'field' => 'agendaNumber',
         'label' => 'Agenda Number',
         'rules' => 'callback_my_function'
    )
);

$this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

I mnot sure if you can validate two input in the same statement but i can see why you get an error

you need to change
`$this->form_validation->set_rules('agendaCode/agendaNumber','my_callback_function);`

to

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('agendaCode','callback_function);
$this->form_validation->set_rules('agendaNumber','callback_function);`

the corrent statement is callback_functionname it has to be callback not my_callback or anotherthing else

reference For

Comment: actually i want to have a parameter in my callback function